# How to use flexible \vspace (with glue) inside a two-column environment with changed line spacing

Tags: multicol

I have a two-column environment with changed `\baselinestretch` and want to insert a `\vspace` with glue before each paragraph. But instead of adjusting the vspace to the height of the column, the column is extended at the bottom. In case there is only a paragraph break in one of both columns, this results in one column being longer than the other.

This problem occurs only when the line spacing has been changed, either by changing `\baselinestretch` or by `\linespread`. It occurs when using the `multicol` package, but also with `twocolumn` as an option of documentclass. As far as I can see, it is also independent of the values chosen for the `\vspace`.

As the formatting specifications of the project (a dictionary parts of which have already been printed) are very strict, changing the format is not an option.

Here is minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}

\newcommand{\spc}{\vspace{12pt plus 12pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum*[1-6]
\par\spc
\lipsum*[7-12]
\par\spc
\lipsum*[13-14]
\par\spc
\lipsum*[15-20]
\par\spc
\lipsum*[21-25]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

In the result, we can see that every column with a `\par\vspace` in it is extended, resulting in an uneven bottom on pages 2 and 4. Here, for example, the second page:
[image: Page 2: Left column wrongly extended]

I hope someone could tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the first thing to observe is that the height of the page is not an integral multiple of the baseline value plus the height of the first line.  (that is obvious from the height of the second, solid, column.)  given that limitation, it will be very difficult to get a uniform bottom baseline when any stretch is involved between paragraphs.

Comment: why are you adding `\vspace` explicitly rather than just changing `\parskip` ? but either way , since your paragraph space is not a multiple of \baseineskip and the the page height is not a multiple of baselineskip either there is no way to make the text exactly fit the specified space/

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
@David Carlisle: In fact, I need two different spaces, a bigger and a smaller one, so I think I can't do this by adjusting \parskip.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I tried also with multiples of \baselineskip, for example: \vspace{1\baselineskip plus .5\baselineskip}; but as long as any glue is involved, the problem is the same.

Comment: @OvC yes of course, if there is stretch glue then the column can be made to its specified `\textheight` but a column with just text and no headings or paragraph breaks  always has the last baseline at `\topskip +n\baselineskip` so if `\textheight` is not of that fom they will not align

Comment: for two different skips I would still not use two vspace in the document, presumably one level is a paragarph break and the bigger one is some "invisible section heading" so I'd use `\newidea` or some such command even if it is just `newcommand\newidea{\par\vspace{somethig}`  it allows the style to be changed without changing the document. (but the column height question is same in any case:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not that the left column is extended, the right column is necessarily short as only that many lines fit and one more line would be too long. Conversely the left hand column is the specified height as the paragraph space (which should be specified by setting `\parskip` not by adding `\vspace` at each break) extends to push the last line to the specified `\textheight`.

You should always make textheight a multiple of (the new) baselineskip+topskip

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}\normalfont
\setlength\textheight{\dimexpr\topskip+47\baselineskip}
\setlength\parskip{12pt plus 12pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum*[1-6]

\lipsum*[7-12]

\lipsum*[13-14]

\lipsum*[15-20]

\lipsum*[21-25]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your solution with two `\vspace`s, and it works perfectly (I will have to study it somewhat more to understand how exactly it does). Many thanks, that was a great help to me!